# Meaning of the random variable Y=|X|

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am learning this and having a very basic doubt. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables where $X$ takes the values $-2,-1,0,1,2$ each with probability $1/5$ and $Y=|X|$.

I think $Y=|X|$ means $Y$ takes the values $0,1,2$ with probability function $P(Y=y)=P(X=-y)+P(X=y)$. I could be wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Technically no, $P(Y=0) = \frac{1}{5} \neq \frac{2}{5} = P(X=-0) + P(X=0) $. It's just $P(Y= y) = P(|X| = y)$.

Comment: $P[Y=y]=P[X\in\{-y, y\}]$ would be okay; and this is $P[X=-y]+P[X=y]$ for $y\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that's right. So $P(Y=0)=1/5$, $P(Y=1)=2/5$ and $P(Y=2)=2/5$.